# Getting z coordinates from polygon list of Geodataframe?

Tags: python, geopandas

I am using Python to solve a problem with many polygons that could be really stressful with other software related to my field (mining), however i havent found a way to extract the Z coordinates from the Shapefile that I am working with.

Comment: every polygon is already in the same Z coordinate, so there wont be trouble if i can get each vertice or just one vertice or the centroid Z coordinate

Answer (score 1):

You can use exterior and interior methods to extract the coordinates as tuples (x,y,z). I belive this should work for both polygon and multipolygons with any number of interior rings:

```
import geopandas as gpd
df = gpd.read_file('/home/bera/GIS/test/zpoly.shp')

def give_z(x):
    if x.type == 'Polygon':
        x = [x]
    zlist = []
    for polygon in x:
        zlist.extend([c[-1] for c in polygon.exterior.coords[:-1]])
        for inner_ring in polygon.interiors:
            zlist.extend([c[-1] for c in inner_ring.coords[:-1]])
    return zlist
    #return sum(zlist)/len(zlist) #In your case to get mean. Or just return zlist[0] if they are all the same

df['z'] = df.geometry.apply(give_z)
```